# Is there a self-cleaning container or similar that limits its entries to k occurences?

Tags: c++, vector, stack, containers

Self-cleaning vector.

I am looking for a data type similar to `vector<T>` or `stack<T>`, that takes entries of type `<template T>`, where each entry occurs a maximum of *k* times. If *k* is exceeded, all occurrences over *k* are deleted.

Comment: There is no standard container for this.  You'll need to implement this yourself.  What actual problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: On the surface it sounds like you're asking for a circular buffer / list.  But your description also suggests you're wanting to group elements like a `std::multiset` but limit the size of the set.  Please add details of the desired behavior and provide examples.  The most straight-forward approach would be to maintain a book-keeping structure with the relevant counts of what is in your other container, and encapsulate the interface to ensure it stays in sync.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can solve the problem like this...

```cpp
#include <map>

template <typename _Tp>
class bag {
public:
    bag(int __k) : _M_k(__k) {}

    void put(const _Tp &__val) {
        if (_M_map.count(__val) && _M_map[__val] == _M_k - 1) 
            _M_map.erase(__val);
        else 
            ++_M_map[__val];
    }

    // .....
    // add yourself 
private:
    std::map<_Tp, int> _M_map;
    int _M_k;
};
```

Comment: nice that works for me